# Emacs org-mode gnuplot : Error running timer: (void-variable data-file)

Tags: emacs, gnuplot, org-mode

Whenever I call the command `org-plot/gnuplot` in emacs org-mode,  I get the same error `Error running timer: (void-variable data-file)`. I am using emacs 24.4.1 in Debian Jessie as well as emacs 24.5 on a Mac Os.  Both systems have a working version of gnuplot. I even try this command when running emacs with no .emacs files and still get this same error.

Comment: Show your code. Give a recipe of what you are doing, starting from `emacs -Q`. Turn on `debug-on-error` and show the backtrace. Etc. And a wild guess is that you evaluated some code (e.g. a lambda form) that uses a lexical variable (`data-file`) by simply taking it out of context from a file that has lexical binding turned on by a local variable declaration.

Comment: Thanks, the -Q option allows me to to figure out that something about gnuplot was not compiled right.  Though still not able to fix the issue.

Comment: Ran into same error also.

Answer (score 5):

It is a bug. The function org-plot/gnuplot (in org-plot.el) hasn't yet been updated to account for lexically-scoped variables.  You can fix it in your emacs installation (assuming you have the .el files installed) by first finding the org-plot.el source file (one way is to do

```
m-x apropos ^org-plot/gnuplot$
```

and then clicking on the file link at the top of the result) and replacing the last expression in the org-plot/gnuplot function (use c-m-f to get to the end quickly)

```
(run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil (lambda () (delete-file data-file)))
```

to instead read

```
(run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil (lambda (data-file) (delete-file data-file)) data-file)
```

The original code was expecting the lambda to close over the dynamic data-file variable, but it is now lexical. My replacement code passes the value directly into the lambda.

You will have to save the modified file and then recompile it with

```
m-x byte-compile-file
```

or you'll just see a warning that the .el file is newer (but it will load the .elc with the old code anyway).

I wouldn't be surprised if this is fixed in newer versions of org, but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Found it! See original answer below. In it, I find the line which refers to `data-file`. The comments in the original source file around that line mention that changes were made to accomodate gnuplot 4. That, together with @vu-nguyen's comment, led me to download and compile [gnuplot 4.6.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.6.7/gnuplot-4.6.7.tar.gz/download) .

I compiled and installed it thus:

```
./configure --with-cwdrc --with-readline=gnu --enable-backwards-compatibility
make
sudo make install
```

And it started working.

### Original Answer

I deleted my `elpa` folder and reinstalled my elpa packages to make sure I wasn't using "dirty" package folders. EDIT: I even uninstalled the newest version of the `gnuplot` package and installed older versions (`20140317` and `0.6.6`) but nothing helped.

It looks like the only package that talks about `data-file` is gnuplot:

`gnuplot.el:2820:        ("(gnuplot)data-file"     nil "[_a-zA-Z0-9]+")`

Maybe it is a bug?